# 'It's for your good' versus 'It's for your own good'

Tags: phrases, pronouns, construction, reflexives

I'm wondering whether *for your good* is commonly used in English-speaking countries. For example,

> 1. Take the medicine. That's for your good.

If that is not grammatical or idiomatic for some reason, why not?

And what should one use instead?

Comment: This is probably a better fit over at [ell.se] - they're netter at answering questions like 'is this grammatical'

Comment: @Mitch Not here, because it's not at all clear why *own* is required for the sentence to be grammatical.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. OK that's a reasonably interesting thing to consider. Unfortunately it's not at all addressed by the current answers, they simply say "your own good" is OK, but "your good" is not, without any attempt at clarification.

Comment: @Mitch Well, John's answer does mention that it requires a reflexive intensifier, (although it does not say why). [ Although it's reflexive, I disagree that it's an intensifier here, because otherwise it would be optional, which It isn't!)

Answer (score 7):

*For s.o's good* is not used alone in English.

- *Take your medicine. It's for your cold.*
- *Take your medicine.* **It's for your good*

Normally it's accompanied by *own* (a reflexive intensifier) preceding and modifying *good*.

- *Take your medicine. It's for your own good.*

There is also a pragmatic narrative of stubbornness suggested here. Why should one have to remind anyone of their own good? They must have been resistant to taking the medicine, goes this story.

Comment: And presumably necessary because the *you* here plays a specific semantic role with regards to the noun *good* (i.e. is the beneficiary of the goodness/who its good *for*).

Comment: The full OED has a couple of dozen citations for this "good" = "benefit" sense. All except one either feature preceding reflexive *[for someone's] **own** good*, or they're followed by the prepositional element *[for the] good **of** [the nation, party, etc.].* The one exception is *You think no one knows any thing about you; but every thing has been discovered by me; and I cannot help thinking that it has been made known providentially, and **for your good**.* Perhaps that one's "kinda okay" because "agent" & beneficiary are *different people* (so "reflection" is less relevant).

Comment: Also it's very old, so it's kinda ok.

Answer (score 2):

Brit here. It's OK, but perhaps a little old fashioned. You are more likely to hear, "It'll do you good," or "It's for your own good."

Comment: +1 “It’s for your own good”   Gotta have the “own”

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.- The strangest thing.  The iPhone app wasn't letting me upvote. "Could not perform this request with this account"...  Had to wait to get on my laptop.